# How to create ASP.NET 4.0 pages contain controls under roles (Admin or not)

Tags: asp.net, roles, usergroups

I want to build web pages using ASP.NET 4.0 (C#), and I want some controls to be appear for the admin role for example. And disappear for the normal user.

I suggested the (Multiview) standard control!

The question is: Is this method PERFECT? or there are many better methods to apply?

Comment: Why are you using multiview in this case? you can use Panels to show or hide then.

Comment: It works, right.

but I'm asking for the perfect method.

Thanks Shoaib :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless some new way of doing this has been introduced in asp.net 4.0 then this is the correct way of doing this, it is exactly what the MultiView control was designed to do.